# Rails find_or_initialize_by not inserting data only "created_at", "updated_at"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord

I am trying to pull data from a csv and insert into database using rake. For some reason the insert statement is not including the data provided. As you can see in the Development.log file it searches for the correct record which does not exist then it tries to create the record. but only inserts date stamps for "created_at", "updated_at".

I am new to rails so it might be something very easy, but i was unable to find an answer online.I have been trying to figure out why its not working all day, any help is greatly appreciated

USDAData.csv

```
"ABELI","Abelia","abelia"
"ABGR4","Abelia ×grandiflora","glossy abelia"
"ABELM","Abelmoschus","okra"
"ABES","Abelmoschus esculentus","okra"
"ABMA9","Abelmoschus manihot",""
```

USDAData.rake

```
namespace :USDAData do
  desc "import data from USDA to database"
    task :import => :environment do
    file = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'USDAData.csv'))

    file.each do |line|
        attrs = line.split(",")
        @Accepted_Symbol = attrs[0].gsub!(/\A"|"\Z/, '')
        @Scientific_Name = attrs[1].gsub!(/\A"|"\Z/, '').titleize
        @Common_Name = attrs[2].gsub!(/\A"|"\Z/, '').titleize

        p = Plant.find_or_create_by(Accepted_Symbol: @Accepted_Symbol, Scientific_Name: @Scientific_Name, Common_Name: @Common_Name)

    end
  end
end
```

development.log

```
  [1m[36mPlant Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "plants".* FROM "plants" WHERE "plants"."Accepted_Symbol" = ? AND "plants"."Scientific_Name" = ? AND "plants"."Common_Name" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["Accepted_Symbol", "ABELI"], ["Scientific_Name", "Abelia"], ["Common_Name", "Abelia\n"]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "plants" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", "2015-02-19 23:20:54.468007"], ["updated_at", "2015-02-19 23:20:54.468007"]]
  [1m[35m (9.6ms)[0m  commit transaction
  [1m[36mPlant Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "plants".* FROM "plants" WHERE "plants"."Accepted_Symbol" = ? AND "plants"."Scientific_Name" = ? AND "plants"."Common_Name" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["Accepted_Symbol", "ABGR4"], ["Scientific_Name", "Abelia ×Grandiflora"], ["Common_Name", "Glossy Abelia\n"]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "plants" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", "2015-02-19 23:20:54.482516"], ["updated_at", "2015-02-19 23:20:54.482516"]]
  [1m[35m (9.8ms)[0m  commit transaction
  [1m[36mPlant Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "plants".* FROM "plants" WHERE "plants"."Accepted_Symbol" = ? AND "plants"."Scientific_Name" = ? AND "plants"."Common_Name" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["Accepted_Symbol", "ABELM"], ["Scientific_Name", "Abelmoschus"], ["Common_Name", "Okra\n"]]
```

plant.rb

```
class Plant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :Accepted_Symbol, :Scientific_Name, :Common_Name
  validates :Accepted_Symbol, presence: true, :null => false
  validates :Scientific_Name, presence: true, :null => false
  validates :Common_Name, presence: true

  before_save :test

  def test
    puts "test: #{@Accepted_Symbol}"
  end

end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150218210119) do

  create_table "plants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "Accepted_Symbol"
    t.string   "Scientific_Name"
    t.string   "Common_Name"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

end
```

Rails Console > Plant.first(5)

```
>> Plant.first(5)
  Plant Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "plants".* FROM "plants"  ORDER BY "plants"."id" ASC LIMIT 5
=> [#<Plant id: 1, Accepted_Symbol: nil, Scientific_Name: nil, Common_Name: nil, created_at: "2015-02-19 23:20:54", updated_at: "2015-02-19 23:20:54">, 
#<Plant id: 2, Accepted_Symbol: nil, Scientific_Name: nil, Common_Name: nil, created_at: "2015-02-19 23:20:54", updated_at: "2015-02-19 23:20:54">,
#<Plant id: 3, Accepted_Symbol: nil, Scientific_Name: nil, Common_Name: nil, created_at: "2015-02-19 23:20:54", updated_at: "2015-02-19 23:20:54">, 
#<Plant id: 4, Accepted_Symbol: nil, Scientific_Name: nil, Common_Name: nil, created_at: "2015-02-19 23:20:54", updated_at: "2015-02-19 23:20:54">, 
#<Plant id: 5, Accepted_Symbol: nil, Scientific_Name: nil, Common_Name: nil, created_at: "2015-02-19 23:20:54", updated_at: "2015-02-19 23:20:54">]
```

The before_save outputs the symbol, thus adding to the confusion. The data is making it all the way to the active-record but then those attributes are dropped from the insert statement.

SOLVED:
The issue was `attr_accessor :Accepted_Symbol, :Scientific_Name, :Common_Name` in my Plant.rb model, as suggested by Jordan Dedels. Marked as answered.

Comment: I just setup a new Rails 4.2 project with your exact code and it worked fine.  Maybe the problem is in your Plant model.  Can you add that to your question?

Comment: Added as requested. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr_accessor` should only be used for attributes you *do not* want to store in the database. Remove this line and it should work:

`attr_accessor :Accepted_Symbol, :Scientific_Name, :Common_Name`

Comment: The attributes are snake/camel case. I have attached the plant.rb and schema.rb for reference.